# Perl telnet doesn't return output

Tags: perl, cmd, output, telnet

I'm having a problem with my perl script. The Script executes a command on a server which takes approximately 10-30 seconds to process and return output that contains like 70 lines.

```
$t = new Net::Telnet (Timeout => 200, dump_log  => $file, input_log => $file1, output_log => $file2);
$t->open($host);
$t->waitfor('/User name:$/i');
$t->print($username);
$t->waitfor(match => '/User password:$/i');
$t->print($passwd);
#$t->waitfor('/.*(#|>|\))\s*$/');
@lines =  $t->cmd(string => @komenda, Timeout => 4000);
39 $t->waitfor('/----
------------------------------------------------------------------------
-/');
$t->getlines();

print @lines;
```

pattern match read eof at melt.pl line 39

I'v changed code to

```
        $t = new Net::Telnet (Timeout => 200, dump_log  => $file, input_log => $file1, output_log => $file2);
$t->open($host);
    $t->waitfor('/User name:$/i');
    $t->print($username);
    $t->waitfor('/User password:$/i');
    $t->print($passwd);
    #$t->waitfor('/.*(#|>|\))\s*$/');
   39 @lines =  $t->cmd(string => @komenda,timeout => 2000);
sleep(50);
#$t->waitfor('/----------------------------------------------------------
  -------------------/');
  #@linie = $t->getlines();
    print @linie;
```

and this returns

pattern match read eof at melt.pl line 39

All log files contain output of this command.

Here comes the question, what am I doing wrong?

Comment: I see several problems. `@komenda` should be just a scalar, maybe `join (' ', @komenda)`, but I don't know what the array contains. `cmd` returns only a value for success. rather use `@lines = $t->getlines`. Can you try with a simple command like `ls -l` or `echo hello` and see if it works? We cannot really reproduce it if we don't see the actual command.

Comment: Changed variable to scalar and command to show version 
pattern match read eof at melt.pl line 36

also tried sending command to server using paste() and then getlines()
and i got 
read timed-out at melt.pl line 39

@lines = $t->getlines;